# Java: Numb1 and Numb2 , and check whether the numb1 has the prefix Numb2

Tags: java

```
public class Good {
    public static boolean hasPrefix (int number , int prefix ) {
        if(number>0){
            System.out.println("num is:"+number+" prefix: "+prefix);
            if(number==prefix) 
                return true ;
 
            number=number/10;
            hasPrefix(number,prefix);
        }
        return false;
    }
 
     public static void main ( String [] args ) {
         System.out.println(hasPrefix(12345,1234)) ;
     }
 }
```

the program should return true if the prefix given is a true prefix of the number. But my program returns false.
e.g

System.out.println(hasPrefix(12345 , 1) ) ; // true

System.out.println(hasPrefix(12345 , 123) ) ; // true

System.out.println(hasPrefix(12345 , 34) ) ; // false

System.out.println(hasPrefix(12345 , 0) ) ; // false

I don't know where is the problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: You're missing the "return" keyword before your recursive call to hasPrefix(number, prefix), so it will always continue below to the "return false;" line.

Answer (score 1):

Convert them both to strings, then use the startsWith method to check if "number" starts with "prefix"

```
public static boolean hasPrefix(int number, int prefix){
        String numberAsString = Integer.toString(number);
        String prefixAsString = Integer.toString(prefix);
        if(numberAsString.startsWith(prefixAsString)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, this issue can be solved using String concept. also given below.

```
public static boolean hasPrefix(int number, int prefix) {
        return String.valueOf(number).startsWith(String.valueOf(prefix)) ? true :false;
    }
```

will work the same in one line.